# Matrix4 parameter acting differently when passed to Transform indirectly

Tags: dart, flutter

I've run into a really weird issue. This is like some type confusion?

If I write my animation like this, it works as expected:

```
Widget _animatedButtonsBuilder(BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
    final animTarget = state.isPhoneNumberFocused
        ? _controller.lowerBound
        : _controller.upperBound;

    _controller.animateTo(animTarget);

    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    //final transform = Matrix4.translationValues(_animation.value * width, 0.0, 0.0)..scale(1.0, 1.0-_animation.value, 1.0);

    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(_animation.value * width, 0.0, 0.0)..scale(1.0, 1.0-_animation.value, 1.0),
            child: new RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Login'),
              color: Color(0xff938065),
              elevation: 4.0,
              splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              textColor: Color(0xffffffff),
              onPressed: () {},
          ));
    });
  }
```

but if I uncomment

```
//final transform = Matrix4.transla...
```

and passed that to the `transform:` parameter, it doesn't seem to work right.

What's happening?

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work right." mean exactly?

Comment: The button should start off-screen, and ease onto the screen from the right. Instead, it starts on-screen, and disappears/appears instead of easing.

Comment: Can't imagine your mentioned code change to cause this difference.

Comment: I can only think of something like implicit constructors/conversions, or something like boxing??

Comment: I'm sure there is no such thing happening here. You could try moving the `final transform = ...` line just before `return Transform(...`. At this place the line will be executed much more often and probably with different results.

Comment: `"The button should start off-screen, and ease onto the screen from the right"` - and why dont you use `SlideTransition` (or `AnimatedAlign` for example)?

Comment: I want to shrink the thing vertically as well, so that it doesn't take up vertical space when invisible... will look into SlideTransition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to get equivalent result you'd need to move the line into the builder,
because there it is executed every time the animation progresses, not only at the start of the animation.

```
Widget _animatedButtonsBuilder(BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
    final animTarget = state.isPhoneNumberFocused
        ? _controller.lowerBound
        : _controller.upperBound;

    _controller.animateTo(animTarget);

    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          //final transform = Matrix4.translationValues(_animation.value * width, 0.0, 0.0)..scale(1.0, 1.0-_animation.value, 1.0);

          return Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(_animation.value * width, 0.0, 0.0)..scale(1.0, 1.0-_animation.value, 1.0),
            child: new RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Login'),
              color: Color(0xff938065),
              elevation: 4.0,
              splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              textColor: Color(0xffffffff),
              onPressed: () {},
          ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Oh duh! you're actually inside a lambda there. I'm dumb. Thanks!